# Error $ is not defined in django with DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am developing an app in django. I copy some js files to the static/admin/js folder to use bootstrap and jquery DataTables.
The css style load fine, but I always receive the error:

> ReferenceError: $ is not defined $(document).ready(function() {

I call the jquery library with different ways and always receive the same error 
This are the ways try to load the jquery libray

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="{{STATIC_URL|default:"/static/"}}admin/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

<script src="{{STATIC_URL|default:"/static/"}}admin/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
```

This the function that have the error:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#myTable').dataTable();
        });
        $(function() {
            $('.list-group-item').click(function() {
                $('.panel-collapse.in').collapse('hide');
            });
        });
</script>
```

I check with firebug and apparently all the Javascript library are loaded without any issue.

I don't know if my error is the way I call the library or the javascript function to use DataTable or where I have the error.

Comment: Is your code before or after the reference to jQuery?

Comment: Thanks Jack I put the calls in the header and works great. noob error

Comment: Why do you have jquery included 3 times?

Comment: I don't include three times, I wanna show the ways I try to include the libray. I only use one. but my error was I'm calling the library after the function. I change the to call the library before the function and works fine. thanks